# SPF with a Mail Gateway: do I need to put all my mail servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, spf

I always put all my Mail Servers in SPF declarations, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement SPF.

All my mail got routed through a Mail Gateway. Everything goes first to this server and then relayed to the internet.

The question is: Considering that the Mail Gateway is my MX record in DNS and with this architecture should I wrote the SPF settings in this way:

```
example.com.        86400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Or should I put additional `A` records for the internal servers?

Comment: Don't confuse your MX records with your SPF records. They're not necessarily the same host(s). The MX record designates where email goes `TO` for a particular domain and the SPF record designates where email comes `FROM` for a particular domain.

Comment: I'm not confusing... I use the same server for inbound and outbound relay. All mail gets in on the MX and the internal servers uses a "send connector" to the outbound server which is the same as the Mail Exchanger (MX).

Comment: I understood that from your question but because you referenced your MX record in your question about your SPF record I wanted to clarify that the two records are for email going in the opposite directions. MX = In and SPF = Out. The reason you would put the MX record mechanism in your SPF record would be if your inbound email server is also your outbound email server, which is very common but not always a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough. Any server on the internet would see only your gateway as the originator of the email and won't care about any internal servers the mail originated from.

Comment: That's my question: this should be enough or this is enough. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to say, because **you have no control over whether someone else decides to accept your email**.  They can, and sometimes do, decline your mail for reasons which are RFC-violating as well as dumb.

As proteus has said, the record you have shown *should* be enough to certify the email as coming from you; it certainly satisfies [RFC 7208](http://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=7208) as I understand it.  But I have known some large organisations reject email because of the servers it has passed through on the way out of my clients' networks.  They shouldn't have been doing any kind of checking on the `Received: from` headers other than the one that led to final connection, but they were.  In that particular case, one of the internal servers had an unqualified hostname, and the footprint that left in the headers caused the recipient to reject it.  They were awfully sorry when this was pointed out, but (as is so depressingly common these days) they had outsourced their email and so had no control over this decision.  We ended up having to set up full internal DNS to enable emails to go through to them.

The point of that story is that they could just as easily have decided to apply SPF tests to all the relays prior to final delivery.  You don't know what boneheaded stunt some idiot is going to pull.  You can only honour the RFCs (as you are), hope for the best, and deal with the worst when it arrives.